# I'm trying to display my data in the Line Chart but I'm having trouble to convert my data type . to int and LocalDateTime

Tags: charts, line

```
public class AnalyserDashboardController extends Controller {
    public LineChart<Number, LocalDateTime> lineChart;
    public NumberAxis xAxis;
    public NumberAxis yAxis;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        Singleton.getInstance().addSceneHistory("view/AnalyserDashboard.fxml");
```

//I lode the all my result from database and list them in table
            List results = DatabaseHandler.loadAll(Result.class);

```
        lineChart.setTitle("Line chart");
        xAxis.setLabel("xAxis");
        yAxis.setLabel("yAxis");
```

//adding new series to put my data to it so I can view how many results I have in princelier date. 
            XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series<>();
            series.setName("all results");
            int counter = 0;
            for (Result result : results) {
                counter++;
                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(counter,result.getDateTime()));
//I need to add put all my result date in line chart .

```
        }
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
    }
}
```